# DateTime.ParseExact gives String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, datetime

I'm trying to parse a date string into a `DateTime` variable. I've found out that `ParseExact` is the way to do it, but I try this I get the error:

**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

```
string timeFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss";
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(reader["startdate"].ToString(), timeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime nextDate = DateTime.ParseExact(reader["nextdate"].ToString(), timeFormat, null);
```

I've tried both with `null` (which happens to work on another page), and the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

`reader["startdate"].ToString()` output: 01-08-2012 15:39:09

and

`reader["nextdate"].ToString()` output: 01-08-2012 15:39:09

I think it should work, but it doesn't.

Somebody have an idea what is wrong? :)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You're using `hh` in your format string. That's a 12-hour "hour of day" field. The value 15 isn't in range...

You want `HH` instead, which is the 24-hour specifier.

See the [MSDN custom date and time format strings documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Ofcourse. So when I said it worked on another page, I was just lucky it was before 12 last time I tested. But this works. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: And pretty fast answer btw. I cant even accept the the answer yet :)

Comment: oh my god thanks for this... just took me half a day to figure this out

Comment: My takeaway: for datetime strings in API documentation example payloads, make sure both the hour and the day are each greater than 12. I'd much rather spend extra time finding the right format string than have runtime errors.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably due to the difference between your Server locale and the UI locale

One easier method will be to specify the globalization details in the web.config

like

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <globalization culture="en-GB"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

OR in more detail

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

But be sure this wont clash with your application in general

Comment: This fixed my issue, even though I was specifying the culture DateTime.ParseExact(stringToConvert, format, new CultureInfo("en-NZ")); and I made sure the regional settings were the same on both dev machine and prod server - it would work locally but not on prod.

Answer (score 0):

try this it works

```
DateTime.ParseExact("01-08-2012 15:36:25", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
```

Comment: Yup.. It was just the hh that needed to be HH :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps but I used the exact code from this article and it worked for me because the DateTime.ParseExact(dat, "dd/MM/yyy HH:MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None) did not work for me.

Read this I just posted it online:
http://rochcass.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/error-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-solution/#more-350